# How JVM inccurs paging in/out even though I limit the maximum heap space size?

Tags: java, jvm

I am a newbie on Java.

I run an application on top of distributed framework implemented in Java.
The application is disk and network I/O intensive job.

Each machine has 32 GB memory. I run 4 workers per machine and assign 7 GB maximum heap space for each of them. So in total, there are 28 GB memory space reserved for JVMs. The remaining 4 GB is reserved for OS (Cent OS 7). There were no heavy programs that are concurrently running.

Surprisingly, when I monitor the system resource usage by **dstat**, there are significant amounts of paging are occurring.

How can it be possible? I restricted the memory usage of JVMs!

I appreciate your helps, thanks

Comment: Why do you think restricting max heap usage will disable paging? Which framework do you use?

Comment: The heap is not the whole JVM.  The heap is just one memory region (often the most important one, but just one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JVM does not page out memory. The operating system does. How and when the OS chooses which pages to evict depends on configuration.
And setting `-Xmx` *only* configures the upper limit for the managed heap within the JVM. It does not restrict file mappings, direct memory allocations, native libraries or the page caches kept in memory whenever you do IO.

So you have not really "reserved" 28GB for JVMs, because the OS knows nothing about that and the JVMs know nothing of the other JVMs.